# using dictionaries and linked list python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary their key is a word an I want in the elements save a linked list, something like this.

Dictionary

- key    element
- hi     linkedlist1
- hello  linkedlist2

i already make it with arrays

```
dictionari={}
for textoactual in texto:
    archi = open(textoactual,'r')
    lines = archi.readlines()
    for row in lines:
        for word in row.split(' '):
            if word in dictionari:
                aux = dictionari[word] 
                aux_txt = textoactual.replace('.txt','')
                if not(aux_txt in aux): 
                    aux.append(aux_txt)
                    dictionari[word]=aux
            else:
                aux_txt = textoactual.replace('.txt','')
                dictionari[word] = makelist(aux_txt)
```

Comment: what is `text` in line `archi=open(text, 'r')` ? Also you can simply do `row in archi`. You don't have to read all of them into `line` and do a `row in line`. Also - what do you mean by `array`? `if word in dictionari`? Now do you mean `word in dictionari.keys()`. ? There seem quite a few problems with this. Can you please share the sample text file? May be one can then help you get started?

Comment: I've submitted an edit, it's probably textoactual

Comment: `for row in lines` reads kinda weird. Why not `for line in lines`?

Comment: So, basically you're asking how to implement a linked list in python?

Comment: sorry i didn't explain correctly. i'm reading from a directory many files and i am separating word by word from each file in a single row, then that word i save it in a dictionary as a key  and i want to save in a linked list the name of the files where that word appears.

in the code above i make it with a list but now i want to do it with a linked list

Comment: @OmarSanchez Any reason why you don't want to use a standard array/queue/stack?

Comment: because i want to see what is faster linked list or arrays when i search information @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT3** this might come too late to the show, since the question was accepted over a month ago, yet I've got a thing to add.

In fact Python has a standard C-ish linked list implementation that is the `deque` class in the `collections` module. Here is the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c)

> A `dequeobject` is composed of a doubly-linked list of `block` nodes.

So if you need a fast linked list in Python stick with `deque`.

**EDIT2** based on OP's comment.

> ...because i want to see what is faster linked list or arrays when i
>   search information

Search complexity in a linked list is equal to that in an array (or array-based structures) and is approximately O(n), where n is the number of elements in your container. But since Python built-in data structures are heavily optimized and C-loaded, they will run a lot faster in real-life usage. Linked lists are helpful when you need constant time insertion/deletion at any position of the list or when you don't want to mess with dynamically sized arrays, but it doesn't seem like your case. Since you are actually looking for fast search, you need a hash-table, hence use `set`s to store file names. In order to do this replace the following line in the `match_words_and_files`

```
res.setdefault(word, llist.LinkedList()).insert_with_lookup(file_title)
```

with

```
res.setdefault(word, set()).add(file_title)
```

**EDIT**. OP updated the request. Provided the `LinkedList` stuff is saved in a separate module named `llist`:

```
import os
import llist


def match_words_and_files(directory):
    directory = os.path.abspath(directory)
    res = {}
    for file_name in filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(directory)):
        file_title = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
        with open(os.path.join(directory, file_name)) as inp:
            for line in inp:
                parsed_line = line.rstrip().split()
                for word in parsed_line:
                    res.setdefault(word, llist.LinkedList()).insert_with_lookup(file_title)
    return res
```

**Original post**.

If you want a linked list in Python it can be implemented this way (obviously this is not the only way to do it)

```
class Node(object):
    __slots__ = ["_data", "_next_node"]
    def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
        self._data = data
        self._next_node = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._data)

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    @property
    def next_node(self):
        return self._next_node

    def link_node(self, next_node):
        if not hasattr(next_node, "_next_node"):
            self._next_node = Node(next_node)
        self._next_node = next_node


class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        if head is not None and not isinstance(head, Node):
            self._head = Node(head)
        else:
            self._head = head

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr([repr(node) for node in self.iter_links()])

    def __str__(self):
        return ','.join(str(node) for node in self.iter_links())

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self.iter_links())

    def set_head(self, head):
        self._head = head

    def insert(self, node):
        if not isinstance(node, Node):
            node = Node(node)
        node.link_node(self._head)
        self._head = node

    def insert_with_lookup(self, node):
        """
        Inserts a node if the data it contains is not equal to the one
        stored in the the head node.
        """
        if not isinstance(node, Node):
            node = Node(node)
        if node.data != self._head.data:
            self.insert(node)            

    def iter_links(self):
        current_node = self._head
        while current_node:
            yield current_node
            current_node = current_node.next_node


linked_list = LinkedList(1)
linked_list.insert(2)
linked_list.insert(3)
```

Let's create one and grow it a little

```
print(list(linked_list.iter_links()))
```

The output:

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

P.S.

I don't see a single reason to use a linked list in your case.

Comment: sorry i didn't explain correctly. i'm reading from a directory many files and i am separating word by word from each file in a single row, then that word i save it in a dictionary as a key and i want to save in a linked list the name of the files where that word appears. in the code above i make it with a list but now i want to do it with a linked list

Comment: @OmarSanchez Here you are.

Comment: thanks a lot, just one more question when i print the dictionary with <pre> <code>

Comment: thanks alot, just one more question when i print the dictionary with  result=match_words_and_files(directory)  for key ,value in result.items():  print(key, value)  returns me in value something like this hello object at 0x01E7D5D0, and not the values of the linked list

Comment: @OmarSanchez This happens because the LinkedList class has no `__str__` and `__repr__` methods. I'll add them.

Comment: @OmarSanchez Done. You'd better stick to my recommendation in the second edit of the post. Notice that I've added some minor changes to the `LinkedList` class and the `match_words_and_files` function.